# Sending an Email using the JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I tried to send an email with JavaMail but I received an exception, and I don't know what's going on!

```
public class Mail 
{
private int port = 587;
private String host = "smtp.live.com";
private String from = "myusername@live.com";
private boolean auth = true;
private String username = "myusername@live.com";
private String password = "mypassword";
private Protocol protocol = Protocol.SMTPS;
private boolean debug = true;


@SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body)
{
    Properties outlookProps = new Properties();
    outlookProps.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    outlookProps.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    switch (protocol) {
    case SMTPS:
        outlookProps.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
        break;
    case TLS:
        outlookProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        break;
    }

    Authenticator authenticator = null;
    if (auth) {
        outlookProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        authenticator = new outlookAuthenticator();
    }

    Session session = Session.getInstance(outlookProps, authenticator);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        message.setText(body);
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class outlookAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
        private PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return pa;
        }
}
```

I received this exception:

```
    com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.live.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at net.Mail.sendMail(Mail.java:54)
    at ahmad_Project.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 8 more
```

I don't know what permission denied means, can it be caused because my antivirus is blocking it or something like this?
help please!

Comment: The error means that the OS denies permission to open a TCP socket? Is a firewall blocking outgoing connections? Disable all firewalls for a quick test.

Comment: I disabled all firewalls but still receive the same exception :(

Comment: than it could be an ipv6 problem (u may need -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true), check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110345/i-get-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-when-sending-an-email

Comment: Are you a proxy for network connection that might create connection problems

Comment: you was right, a proxy was blocking connection,

Comment: but now I receive another exception: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: AFAIK live.com uses starttls. Did you try Protocol.TLS?

Comment: I tried TLS and it worked successfully, but I want SMTPS :(

Comment: is TLS secure? because TLS does not use ssl, I'm afraid.

Comment: of course it is, TLS is the current version of SSL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security