# Unable to connect from localhost to localhost in Java

Tags: java, sockets, jvm, localhost, firewall

I wrote simple server-client program to send information from client to server, but it doesn't work with the following errors:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Permission denied
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
```

With the following exception too:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.inthemoon.localhostconnectattempt.LocalhostConnectAttempt$2.run(LocalhostConnectAttempt.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code is following:

```
package net.inthemoon.localhostconnectattempt;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    public class LocalhostConnectAttempt {

        private static String hostName = "localhost";
        private static int portNumber = 444;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


            Thread server = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try ( 
                        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    ) {
                        String inputLine;

                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
                            out.println("heard you");
                            if (inputLine.equals("bye")) {
                                System.out.println("Server: exiting");
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            server.setDaemon(true);
            server.start();

            Thread client = new Thread( new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try (
                        Socket kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
                    ) {

                        out.println("Hello world!");


                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            client.start();




        }



    }
```

**UPDATE**

Disclosing `localhost 127.0.0.1` in `hosts` file didn't help.

**UPDATE 2**

I found the root of the problem: this was caused by [proxy autoconfiguration][1]. By some reason address of `127.0.0.1` was processing by proxy and was leading to the web page of proxy server. The addition of

```
function FindProxyForURL(url,host)
{
   if( host == '127.0.0.1' ) {
      return "DIRECT";
   }
```

to `wpad.dat` helped but I still don't understand an entire effect. I have proxy for a long time and it was no causing such an effect previously.

So I think this is also somehow related with `IPv6` or something.

Comment: On *nix systems you need root privileges in order to listen on ports lower then `1024` (you're using `444`) and that is probably the case on Windows as well.

Comment: @Titus Windows does not give any preferential treatment to ports lower than 1024.

Comment: @Titus I have changed port to 2048 and have the same result. I have some general failure today with many java apps.

Comment: This question may give you an idea on what may be causing this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110345/i-get-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-when-sending-an-email