# Jenkins SSH Permission denied (connect failed)

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh

When I go to Jenkins - Configure System then configure the Publish Over SSH plugin so that it contains the pertinent host and user information and hit the test configuration button, I receive a message beneath the plugin configuration that states:

```
Failed to connect or change directory

jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [l-02_App]. Message [java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (connect failed)]]
```

This same message is output when configuring for use with key authentication, username/password authentication or even when specifying bogus values for user, password or hostname.

Jenkins was installed by dropping the .war file into /usr/share/tomcat/webapps.
I have configured private key authentication so that the user running jenkins (tomcat) can connect using a key and passphrase to the remote server as a user named jenkins. For example I can connect successfully using 
sudo -s -u tomcat 
ssh jenkins@remotehost 
then providing my key passphrase.

As another test I compiled some example code that uses jsch and that test was also successful. https://www.journaldev.com/246/jsch-example-java-ssh-unix-server. I ran the compiled code as the tomcat user and it successfully connected to the remote host and performed an ls.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Full Error message from Jenkins Log:

`

```
Failed to connect session for config [l-02_App]. Message [java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (connect failed)]
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (connect failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util$1.run(Util.java:362)
Caused: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:394)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration.connect(BapSshHostConfiguration.java:380)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration.createClient(BapSshHostConfiguration.java:245)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration.createClient(BapSshHostConfiguration.java:234)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.descriptor.BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.validateConnection(BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.java:181)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.descriptor.BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.doTestConnection(BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.java:176)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.descriptor.BapSshHostConfigurationDescriptor.doTestConnection(BapSshHostConfigurationDescriptor.java:90)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110345/i-get-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-when-sending-an-email) might help you. The error message is the same, just a different port number.

Answer (score 0):

SELinux (enabled by default in RHEL 7.5) was denying tomcat from connecting over ssh. I set selinux to permissive mode to allow the communication.

running `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log`
showed the following after trying to test the SSH connection from within Jenkins.

type=AVC msg=audit(1526906414.031:103): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=1052 comm="java" dest=22 scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ssh_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1526906414.031:103): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=35 a1=7f96e6af54a0 a2=10 a3=220 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1052 auid=4294967295 uid=53 gid=53 euid=53 suid=53 fsuid=53 egid=53 sgid=53 fsgid=53 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="java" exe="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java" subj=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1526906414.031:103): 

After running `setenforce Permissive` I was able to test the connection successfully. I then modified the selinux config so it would maintain permissive mode after a restart. `nano /etc/selinux/config` and set `SELINUX=permissive`

Answer (score 0):

another option is install semodule that denied sshd with below command

```
audit2allow -a
audit2allow -a -M sshd_t
semodule -i sshd_t.pp
```